# Beth cardinals and inacceesible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

Since my last question here about the Alephs was too imprecise and thus went over like a lead balloon, I am trying a new and simpler question which asks what I probably should have asked before.

Under "Beth Numbers" in Wikipedia I read:

"In ZF, for any cardinals $\kappa$ and $\mu$, there is an ordinal $\alpha$ such that:

$\kappa \leq \beth_\alpha(\mu)$."

But under "Inaccessible Cardinals" I read:

"a cardinal $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible if it is uncountable, it is not a sum of fewer than $\kappa$ cardinals that are less than $\kappa$, and $\alpha < \kappa$ implies $2^\alpha < \kappa$."

These two passages are troubling to me since they seem to be contradictory.  The first one seems to imply that for ANY cardinal one can always find a Beth number which exceeds it.  While the second one clearly seems to imply that the first inaccesible and any cardinal larger than it, of which there are uncountably many, of course, are all vastly larger than any Beth cardinal generated by even $\omega$ applications of the Power Set operation could ever be.

I assume that I am simply missing something important here, and that both statements from the Wikipedia are actually true.  But what exactly am I missing??

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to only $\omega$ applications of the power set operation?

Comment: OK, I thought of that and almost said "any number of Power Set operations," but I don't understand what it would be to apply the operation an uncountable number of times, if such is possible at all.

Comment: Maybe you're missing the condition $$\alpha\lt\kappa$$ which appears in one statement but not the other?

Comment: Well, that would certainly change things quite a bit, but no such restriction is placed on the equation in the Beth numbers article.

Comment: @WdFusroy "I don't understand what it would be to apply the operation an uncountable number of times, if such is possible at all." This is **exactly** what's going on here. Are you familiar with transfinite recursion?

Comment: @WdFusroy "no such restriction is placed on the equation in the Beth numbers article." Right, that's what I said. That's why there's no contradiction. If $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible, then $\beth_\alpha\lt\kappa$ for $\alpha\lt\kappa$, but $\beth_\alpha\ge\kappa$ for $\alpha\ge\kappa$. What's the problem?

Comment: An inaccessible cardinal is still an ordinal.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the issue you're having is with understanding what $\beth_\alpha$ means when $\alpha \geq \omega$.  The definition is by recursion: $\beth_0 = \aleph_0$, for any ordinal $\alpha$ we define $\beth_{\alpha+1} = 2^{\beth_\alpha}$, and when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal we have $\beth_\alpha = \sup\{\beth_\beta : \beta < \alpha\}$.  This allows us to continue the powerset operation transfinitely.

Notice that, for every $\alpha$, $\aleph_\alpha \leq \beth_\alpha$.  Thus, if $\kappa = \aleph_\alpha$, then $\beth_\alpha \geq \aleph_\alpha = \kappa$, so it is indeed true that there is a $\beth$ number larger than $\kappa$ (if you want strictly larger, go for $\beth_{\alpha+1}$).

The reason the previous paragraph doesn't contradict the definition of $\kappa$ being inaccessible is that if $\kappa$ is inaccessible then the $\alpha$ for which $\kappa = \aleph_\alpha$ is $\kappa$ itself, i.e., $\kappa = \aleph_\kappa$.  Thus, unlike in the definition of inaccessibility, we're not in the position of calculating $2^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha < \kappa$.

Comment: Well, that all sounds very sensible.  But I am still troubled by your claim that:"if κ is inaccessible then the α for which κ=ℵα is κ itself, i.e., κ=ℵκ."  I have encountered that claim many times before but never been fully comfortable with it since it isn't obvious to me that there could not exist some big cardinal "j" such that there is NO "a," not even j itself, for which j = Aleph[j], or in the case mentioned here, for which j = Beth[j]. More simply put, how can we know, a priori, that many cardinals do not exceed even uncountably infinite recursive Power Set taking altogether?

Comment: I am also still quite troubled by the idea that it would ever be possible to take an uncountable number of recursive Power Set applications.  Since these recursions must always be taken in precise sequence, each one after, and building upon, the previous one, they should always remain countable by some huge, but still denumerable, ordinal index, I think.

Comment: I should probably also say that I am interested in all of these matters primarily because it has always seemed to me that the Power Set operation is far too "slow" to serve as something like an index of the comparative size of various cardinals, which, I assume, was the general idea behind inventing the Beth Numbers in the first place.  There are many other operations, like, say, the tetration operation, i.e. 2 Tet [Super]Beth[n] = [Super]Beth[n+1], which would certainly grow vastly faster than the usual 2 exp Beth[n] = Beth[n+1] But could even that recursion get to any of the inaccessibles??

Comment: There are a few things going on here.  The existence of an inaccessible cardinal is something you could reasonably not believe (in the sense that we don't even know that it is consistent, and indeed there are significant barriers to us knowing that, because ZFC+"there is an inaccessible cardinal" implies Con(ZFC)).

Comment: On the other hand, one can prove in ZFC that there is a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $\aleph_\kappa = \kappa$.  For instance, see the discussion on this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747465/question-about-aleph-fixed-point

Comment: It also sounds like you may be doubting more than either of these things, namely that the $\aleph$'s exhaust all of the cardinals.  Over ZF, the assertion "the cardinality of every set is an $\aleph$" is equivalent to the axiom of choice, so perhaps you have doubts about AC?

Comment: @WdFusroy "Since these recursions must always be taken in precise sequence, each one after, and building upon, the previous one, they should always remain countable by some huge, but still denumerable, ordinal index, I think." No, that's not necessary. Definition by transfinite recursion makes sense along all the ordinals.

Comment: Thanks so much for those helpful comments, Chris and Noah!  I was not aware that ""the cardinality of every set is an ℵ" is equivalent to the axiom of choice, or I wouldn't have asked my previous imprecise Aleph question. Is the proof of this equivalence in Jech or Drake?  I do have some doubts about AC, actually, since it seems to me that it is impossible to pick, say, a random Real number out of I = [0,1] when none of the transcendental numbers, -- which you have a 100% probability of choosing randomly!, -- can even be uniquely specified. ... I will comment on transcendental recursion below.

Comment: @WdFusroy "none of the transcendental numbers [...] can even be uniquely specified." Um, $\pi$?

Comment: The cannot be uniquely specified since no matter how far out one goes trying to name a single unique one, there will always be an uncountably infinite number of other trancendnetals, -- not to mention infintesimals!, --  which share that same initial digital sequence.  In other words, the individual Reals are mostly "unameable."

Comment: @WdFusroy But initial digit sequences aren't the only way we have of naming numbers. (And even if they were, transcendental numbers are no different from algebraic numbers in regard to initial sequences) - $\pi$ is computable, which is a strong notion of namability. For that matter, even the broader claim "most real numbers aren't nameable" is a dangerous one: while it's easy to prove that only countably many real numbers are computable, when we pass to broader notions of definability Tarski's theorem makes things get weird (see [Hamkins, Linetsky, and Reitz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597)).

Comment: Yes, there are, just as you say, Noah, other ways of indicating Real numbers than by specifying their initial digital sequences.  pi is a fine example of one of those.  My point, however, is that whenever one attempts to select a single unique transcendental number out of the Real line one has close to a 100% chance of selecting something that is not computable.

Comment: Worse still, much like with eating Lays potato chips, you can't select "just one" of them. All you can do is choose some long string of digits, but no matter how far you go or which sequence you choose there will still be a uncountable set of possible transcendental numbers available beyond the point where you finally gave up on specifying digits.

Comment: And as for the oft heard objection; "yes, but you can get as close to a single number as you wish" that simply confuses magnitude with cardinality.  Even in the case of the computable pi, one can never avoid the problem that every digit of the sequence which supposedly converges to the single point, pi, in fact doesn't converge at all when it comes to specifying a unique point.  To see this best, I think, it is good to remember that the Real line is deeply holographic and looks exactly the same at every scale, indeed, even at every dimension.

Comment: Thus if one goes searching for a unique point, like say pi, one can simply stretch the scale by more than ten, say by twenty, upon each digital recursion.  In that case it becomes immediately clear that with the addition of each new digit one is actually moving farther away from know where the much sought pi is to be found. In fact, in the limit of this repeated stretching operation, one gets an entire infinite line which can be put into a bijection with R^1, with no clue at all as to where pi might be on it.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler way of stating this same point would simply be to say that Transcendental  "numbers" are, for me anyway, not really numbers at all, but merely infinite sequences of nested open sets, one for each step of the ongoing digital expression, which, while they do indeed get ever smaller when measured by the "metric" on the space, always retain the full cardinality of the whole Real line.  It is that which makes it impossible to "choose" any unique transcendental number without choosing a chunk of the full continuum as well.

Answer (score 4):

Your comments indicate that you are dubious about iterating operations on ordinals more than finitely many times, and very dubious about iterating them uncountably many times. **This is a fundamental point in set theory**. The danger is in thinking of recursive definitions as *processes which need to be carried out*, in which case our "finitary biases" get in the way. Instead, you should think of a recursive definition as "happening all at once." Essentially, we can show that **every recursive description corresponds to a unique function**, and what lets us do this is *transfinite induction*. (It shouldn't be surprising that "we can do recursion for as long as we can do induction.")

Specifically, suppose that $F:Ord\rightarrow Ord$ is a function on ordinals *(or rather, class function; for simplicity I'm assuming we're working in a theory like NBG that makes all this much simpler to say)*. For $\theta>0$ an ordinal, say that a function $G$ **iterates $F$ along $\theta$ starting at $\alpha$** iff

- The domain of $G$ is $\theta$,
- $G(0)=\alpha$,
- for $\beta+1<\theta$ we have $G(\beta+1)=F(G(\beta))$, and
- for $\lambda<\theta$ a limit we have $G(\lambda)=\sup\{G(\beta): \beta<\lambda\}$.

*Incidentally, this last condition is really only a natural thing to do if $F$ is nondecreasing, but strictly speaking this works for any $F$.*

In principle, **there could be many $G$ with this property, or none at all**. However, it turns out that there is only ever exactly one:

> For every $F:Ord\rightarrow Ord$ (= the function to be iterated), $\theta>0$ (= the iteration length), and $\alpha$ (= the starting value), there is exactly one $G$ which iterates $F$ along $\theta$ starting at $\alpha$.
>
> Moreover, the $G$s "cohere" in the sense that if $G$ iterates $F$ along $\theta$ starting at $\alpha$ and $G'$ iterates $F$ along $\theta'$ starting at $\alpha$, with $\theta<\theta'$, then for each $\eta<\theta$ we have $G(\eta)=G'(\eta)$. So in some sense there is a unique way to iterate $F$ along $Ord$.

The proof is by transfinite induction: fixing an arbitrary $F$ and $\alpha$, consider some $\theta$ such that the claim holds for all iteration lengths $<\theta$. Intuitively, if $\theta=\gamma+1$ we just take the $G$ for $\gamma$ and "stick one more value onto it," and if $\theta$ is a limit we "glue the earlier $G$s together." It's a good exercise to turn this vague hint into an actual proof.

The sequence of $\beth$ numbers can be constructed in this way:

- $F$ is the map sending an ordinal $\alpha$ to the cardinality of the powerset of $\alpha$ (which, remember, is itself an ordinal - cardinals are just *initial ordinals*).
- The starting value $\alpha$ is $\omega$: this amounts to setting $\beth_0=\omega$.
- To determine what $\beth_\eta$ should be, we set $\theta=\eta+1$ - or really we pick any $\theta>\eta$, by the "coherence" point above it doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for that very complete explanation, Noah.  I can't quite grasp everything you have written yet but will work hard on it in the next few days.  I find "Essentially, we can show that every recursive description corresponds to a unique function, and what lets us do this is transfinite induction," the crux of the matter, and it strikes me as funny that I have trouble with transfinite recursion of the Beths, when I've never had any problem with the similarly "transfinite" definition of simple functions from R to R! [Still the Beths seem "sequential" in a way the Reals do not.]

Answer (score 2):

Say that a natural number $n$ is "large" if for any number $k$ you'd think of in the next 24 hours, $n>10^k$. Let's go bigger, say $n>k\uparrow^k k$, using the Knuth notation.

Pretty much by definition, $n$ is unimaginably large. So large that for the next 24 hours there is no way you can even imagine it. But tomorrow evening, you'd be sitting with a beer and realize that you can imagine an even larger number. Why is that even possible? Because even though this $n$ is large, almost all the other natural numbers are larger.

Inaccessible cardinals are ordinals. They are incredibly large, yes. But at the end of the day, most ordinals are in fact larger. More cardinals are larger.

If $\kappa$ is inaccessible and $\mu<\kappa$, then we can prove that the smallest $\alpha$ for which $\kappa\leq\beth_\alpha(\mu)$ is in fact $\kappa$ itself. Namely, $\kappa\leq\beth_\kappa(\mu)$, and they are in fact equal, and if $\alpha<\kappa$, then $\beth_\alpha(\mu)<\kappa$ as well. But since $\kappa$ is an ordinal, taking $\alpha=\kappa$ is perfectly valid.

So there is no contradiction there. You can move to $\aleph$ fixed points, whose existence is provable in $\sf ZFC$, and replace the $\beth_\alpha(\mu)$ by $\mu^{+\alpha}$, the $\alpha$th successor of $\mu$. If $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$, and $\mu,\alpha<\kappa$, then $\mu^{+\alpha}<\kappa$. Nevertheless, there is some $\beta$ such that $\mu^{+\beta}\geq\kappa$, in fact a proper class of those $\beta$s. And specifically, $\kappa$ itself works for that.

Comment: Thanks so much Asaf!  I always prize your answers and try to learn from them. Here I love the way you start out with an analogy from the finite case. I've always thought that the study of the "Large Finites" has been relatively neglected by mathematicians, although in recent years it is starting to develop. I've always found it amazing that if one asks someone to pick any natural number of their choice, however cleverly large, it will still fall in the first INFINTESIMAL segment of the whole set of nat. numbers. And so too with the infinite cardinals, even if it sometimes seems less obvious.

Comment: The meat of your answer is however this: "If κ is inaccessible and μ<κ, then we can prove that the smallest α for which κ≤ℶα(μ) is in fact κ itself"  I have certainly learned that basic fact, but as I do not know the proof it still seems less than apodeictic to me. At the risk of making a fool of myself again, I still don't see why k can't be GREATER than even Beth[k] [mu] in some cases. That would just mean that k is so large there is NO "a," not even k, that will put Beth[a] [mu] beyond what we might call, say, the "recursively inaccessible" k.  Why is such an odd thing impossible??

Comment: Perhaps my problem here is as simple as not knowing for sure whether Beth[omega] is a limit cardinal.  I had always assumed it must be, -- since it doesn't get to the inaccessibles -- but now it seems to me like the limit cardinal for the whole class of Beths must come only much farther out -- whatever exactly that means -- if in fact there IS anything like a limit cardinal for the whole sequence, which the answers here seem strongly to indicate there is not.

Comment: One last thing.  If we know that k = Beth[k] [u] do we really know anything new, or Kantianan language "synthetic" about k that we didn't already know from the analytic definition of k?  If not, what is the point in showing that k is also a Beth cardinal, even if one so large that all we can say about it is that it is the k-th such?  That seems very trivial to me.  If the Beths are not supposed to help us index the cardinals, as they do nicely out to Beth[4] or so, what purpose DO they serve.  [Sorry for so many naive questions, but I don't know of any other way to learn this hard subject].

Comment: I think it would be very good for you to do some basic exercises about cardinals, ordinals, and recursive definitions. Most of the questions you raise in the comments are very easy to answer once you have a firm grasp on the basics.

Comment: Yes, I have been doing some basic exercises, and I know I need to do more of them, but the subject is so vast that it is hard to know which concepts are most important to learn first. At present I have no one around with whom to work or from whom to take classes, so I need a tutor. I have been working my way through Drake's  "Intermediate Set Theory," but even that is a hard slog for someone like me who is, as no doubt shows, more of a philosopher than mathematician. Learning subject is a hermeneutical process, and being able to ask a few questions is always better than spinning one's wheels.

Comment: Looking over this again after some time, I notice the statement; "Perhaps my problem here is as simple as not knowing for sure whether Beth[omega] is a limit cardinal."  Now that is a poor way of expressing what I was trying to get at since obviously Beth[omega] is THE limit cardinal for the sequence of all the Beths before it which all have finite subscripts.  But when does the NEXT such limit cardinal arise in the sequence?  Is it with Beth epsilon0?  Or do we need to go all the way to Beth omega1 perhaps?  Or is it one of the infinite number of ordinals between the two?

Comment: Do you mean $\beth_{\omega+\omega}$? Or just generally limit cardinals? For the latter case, that is undecided in ZFC, since it is consistent (i.e., GCH) that $\aleph_\alpha=\beth_\alpha$, but it's also consistent that $\beth_{\alpha+2}$ is a limit cardinal for any fixed $\alpha$.